# Realm, access to object from different thread

Tags: objective-c, realm

I saved objects in array in one thread. Sometimes I need access to it from another thread. How can I achieve this?

```
// Main thread
DownloadVideoObject *obj = [DownloadVideoObject createWithKey:@"13"];
obj.videoURLStr = @"..";
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] addObject:obj];
[self.downloadObjects addObject:obj];

// in another thread
for (DownloadVideoObject *obj in self.downloadObjects) {
    if ([key isEqualToString:obj.key]) { // crash on this line "Realm accessed from incorrect thread"
       // ...
    }
}
```

In `CoreData` I can get object in another thread by `objectId`. How can I do something like this in Realm?

### Edit

I know that I can access to object by primary key, but in another thread I do not access to it. Is saving keys instead of object only right solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you said is correct. Since Realm objects are thread confined, the easiest way to interact with the same Realm object on another thread is to simply refetch it on the new thread, using the primary key.

In response to your edit, yes, placing the primary keys of all of your Realm objects in a new array, and simply passing that to the new thread to allow you to refetch the same objects would be the quickest and easiest way of performing this sort of operation.

As a sidenote, while it IS possible in Core Data to access managed objects from another thread (Whereas Realm explicitly disallows it), it's not recommended since those objects still aren't thread safe, and doing so can potentially lead to instability.

Comment: In CoreData `objectId` property is thread safe. You can use it to fetch object from db in another thread. So you can get object for current thread if you have object in another thread.

Comment: Oh it is? Oh! That's good to know then! In any case, Realm eschews having an equivalent ID property that's inherently present in every `RLMObject` in favour of letting developers dictate their own primary keys. Passing an array of primary keys to a new thread to require the same objects should be no different than that.

Comment: In `CoreData` you create you own primary keys to. `objectId` is internal property. You can't change it. It's readonly, that why property is thread safe. You do not know anything about it until you fetch objet from db. I rewrite code with primary keys, and now always fetch object independently on thread. Seams works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @TiM I'm kind of struggling with  performance issues for bigger sets, when getting the IDs of the fetched objects. I don't know if this is the best approach but I'm retrieving them like this (swift): `let objectIds = listOfResults.flatMap({ $0["objectId"] })`. Any other advices? Or any other well known approaches?